# imagejpeg non present in extension functions

Tags: php, reflection, gd, php-extension

If I try to do `(new ReflectionExtension('gd'))->getFunctions()` I get a list of functions, but `imagejpeg` is not among the results, even if the function is [documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) and works fine in my code.

Do you have any idea why it is not in the output of my call?

Answer (score 0):

Please look proper again

```php
echo "<pre>";
print_r((new ReflectionExtension('gd'))->getFunctions());
echo "</pre>";

// Then ctrl+f with "imagejpeg" on a webpage
```

```php
[imagejpeg] => ReflectionFunction Object
(
    [name] => imagejpeg
)
```

CONFIG: OpenServer (Last version), PHP 7.4

Comment: I expect that to be the correct behaviour, but that's not what I am observing. Possibly it depends on the PHP version, on the extension version, etc etc...